# HTML form not submitted via phone

Tags: html, forms

Good day, I'm wondering why my button **cannot do a submit** inside phone browsers. Please take alook at my form

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" id ='form_id'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tipe</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <select onchange = 'by_brand();' name = 'tipenya' id="tipe" class="form-control select2">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="AR-1">Naughty</option>
                            <option value="AR-6">Les Femmes</option>
                            <option value="AR-10">Matahari</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                               <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <select onchange="brands();" name ='area' id="areanya" class="form-control select2">
                                        <option value="">All</option>
                                        <?php foreach ($area as $areanya) {?>
                                         <option value="<?=$areanya->AreaCode;?>"><?=$areanya->Description;?></option>
                                         <?php } ?>
                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                            </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                               <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Outlet</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <select name='outlet' id="hsl" class="form-control select2">


                                    </select>
                                 </div>
                            </div>

                    <div class="form-group"> 
                         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Tanggal" name="date_search" id="reservation" />

</div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="box-footer pull-right">
                              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" />
                        </div>
            </form>
```

It's working fine when i use any laptop. Can anyone help me?

Here is my full html code

http://pastebin.com/KCEQzW3e

Comment: What phone browser? What OS platform?

Comment: submit button is being clicked or not?

Comment: @mahatmanich my phone android and i'm using chrome. I'm trying too at my friend's phone. My friend using android too

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar i press it and the page isn't refresh. it should refresh right?

Comment: It might be a javascript issue, since you are posing to # in your form action. Check for js errors!

Comment: Are you confirm if button is being really clicked???...may be you should try some hover effects to check.Chances are your button is being overlapped by some div when in mobile mode.

Comment: @mahatmanich i use firebug and there is no error

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar i'll try

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar I was never click the button !!!!. Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1):

First of all try using this to test if the sumbit actually works

```
 <form action="javascript:alert("sumbit button works!");" id='form_id'>
```

if this doesnt work then there is something wrong with your form.

if this works. there is something wrong with the jquery function you used.
try using this to call a function if you click submit:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="#" id ='form_id' onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

I hope this helps.